# Start Windows SNMP Service on Windows 7 / 2008R2 with debugging?

Tags: windows, snmp

I have to write a SNMP Extension Agent DLL in Delphi for Windows 8.1/2012R2:

I already created a skeleton which exports the functions SnmpExtensionInit, SnmpExtensionQuery, SnmpExtensionTrap, SnmpExtensionClose. Most of the function do only some logging, however the SnmpExtensionInit function should be working fine.

When I start the SNMP Service, I can see in my logfiles that the DLL is loaded and SnmpExtensionInit is called. Unfortunately SnmpExtensionClose is called directly behind. So it seems that the SNMP Service unregisters my DLL directly after the bind.

The Problem is, I don't know why. Is there a way to start the SNMP Service with an Debugging turned on. I have only found some descriptions for win2003 / XP :
snmp.exe /debug /loglevel:7 /logtype:2

But it seems that this does not work using newer Windows Editions.
Does anybody know how to enable logging for the SNMP Service?

Kind Regards

Benedikt

Comment: Hi Lex,thanks for the answer...

Comment: Hi Lex,thanks for the answer...
the Problem is, that you have to attach to the running Service (in my case snmp.exe) 
Unfortunately my issue starts when snmp Service is started. The Service loads my dll and calls the call to SnmpExtensionInit function and directly the SnmpExtensionClose function and unloads the dll.
It is not possible for me to attach to the Service.
What I'm looking for is a way to force snmp Service to write to a debug log or to the Windows Event log

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/824344